# ajax returning variables as undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my code where i picked a date from the date picker and tried to pass it to my php page. But when i tried using ajax for it. It returns the variable as undefined. I have no clue about it. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {

        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //the getDate method
        var today = new Date();
        alert(today); // wednesday,aug 12, 2015

        $.ajax({
            url: 'abc.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                var1: selectedDate,
                var2: today
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(var2); //returns undefined
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where did you declare the variable `var2`?

Comment: this should be undefined. that is not the correct way to get the key of obj.

Comment: i think you should alert(data)

Comment: Maybe it should be `data.var2`.

Comment: i think you must need to alert the data not the vars2......

Comment: Looks like you want `alert(today);` or the ajax option data or...???

Comment: Thnks for helping .cant do it by alert(data). Any other solution.I have tried all this. But nothing is getting me the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But when i tried using ajax for it. It returns the variable as undefined.*

The way you have written your code the output is correct. *That should be **undefined***. Because you are trying to alert a js object key and you cannot use that key without refering to the object itself.

so if you do this:

```
var obj = { var1 : selectedDate, var2 : today };
```

and pass this object in your ajax and refer to the `object.key` to get the `var2` this way `alert(obj.var2);`:

```
    $.ajax({
         url: 'abc.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: obj,
         success: function(data){
             alert(obj.var2); //returns todate now.
             console.log("success");
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx a tonne sir. This worked for me and i learnt something because of you. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: how should i retrieve the value in php ?

Comment: $_REQUEST['var2']; or $_POST['var2'];

Comment: @ManojDhiman sir , this way is not retrieving me the value in php. I need help. Because i have always retrieved it this way

Comment: @akshara You can post your abc.php code here. make sure  `$_REQUEST['var2']; or $_POST['var2'];` is written in the `<?php ?>` block.

Comment: <?php       $var=$_POST['var2'];
error_log ($var); //returns null
?>

Comment: @akshara where are you testing it on localhost or in the filesystem?

Comment: check in the firbug is it going to right file . or what is is posting or what it is getting in response . check this http://goo.gl/mvtb9H

Comment: and you should use echo

Comment: i am working on linux and for error log i used /etc/httpd/logs/error_log. If i try echo . It doesnt work again. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: @Jai sir Thanks . I was doing some silly mistake. Now its working the way i wanted it to. U are just so great. Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 0):

`var2` is not actually defined except as a key in your parameters you are passing to the script.

If you are outputting `var2` from `abc.php` then you access it by parsing `data` as JSON or setting the content type to JSON and using `data['var2']`

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //the getDate method
        var today=new Date();
        $.ajax({
             url: 'abc.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { var1 : selectedDate, var2 : today },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data['var2']);
                 console.log("success");
             }
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply sir. :) You guys are just great people making us learn so much in just minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

`var2` is not a variable it is just a key by which you are sending the data to the server. 
you can fetch data on the server page `abc.php` like

```
echo $_REQUEST['var2'];
```

and this will return in the success method

```
success: function(data){
            alert(data); //returns undefined
            console.log("success");
        }
```

which will alert the value of data fetched from server.